# Why can't Gmail view an image whose URL comes from google charts?

Tags: url, gmail

Here is an image generated from google's chart API. 
[image]

The url to generate the image is:

> http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxl=0:|day|1:|installs&chxp=0,3|1,6072&chxr=0,0,6|1,0,12145&chxs=0,676767,11.833,0,lt,676767|1,676767,12.833,-0.333,lt,676767&chxt=x,y&chs=400x200&cht=lxy&chds=0,6,0,12145&chd=t:1,2,3,4,5,6|768,2850,6498,10948,12145,0&chdl=installs&chdlp=b&chls=1&chma=5,5,5,1&chtt=installs_per_day

GMail will not (cannot) display this image if it's included in an HTML email.
(e.g. generate and programatically send an email through gmail smtp, or use the gmail labs image insert feature, etc)

Why? Is that a bug? Is there something about encoding URLs for HTML used in emails that I'm missing?

Comment: chtt=installs%20per%20day at the end to have spaces. I couldn't live with the underscores.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Have tried everything. Please notify when you have it solved - I will do the same. Very annoying problem :-|

Answer (score 2):

That is indeed strange. I can confirm the behavior with the Labs feature you mentioned.

I don't know a lot about email encoding but the resulting message *seems* correct--you can [see it in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/1282247) but doesn't display correctly in Gmail. When I do Inspect Element on the non-image in Gmail it appears that the `<img>` element has `title` and `alt` attributes but no `src`. Have you tried viewing it in another email client?

It certainly seems like a bug. I'd suggest bringing it up on Gmails' help forums. While GOOG itself isn't particularly responsive there you may find other people who have more insight into this issue.

A workaround that does appear to work, however, is shortening the URL beforehand. I tested it with both TinyURL and Goo.gl and it worked fine, at least when viewed in Gmail (the top message is with the full URL, the bottom is with the Goo.gl-shortened URL:

[image: Shortened]

Sorry that's not a complete answer to your question, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Checking it from OSX's Mail app is fine.

Comment: I've submitted a bug report to Google.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for reporting it. Can you share a link to the bug?

Comment: The reporting site provided no link to track progress. I filed the bug here:  https://mail.google.com/support/bin/request.py?contact_type=inproduct&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue at WizVille, and think we found why this happens : the charts API returns a URL beginning by "//" which should be interpreted as "http://", but some email clients, like gmail, just don't.

The solution is to specify the protocol, namely "http:", before the chart's URL Google Charts returns. Et voilà !

:-)

Comment: Good solution, but it's incorrect to say that something beginning with // should be interpreted as "http://". WizVille is giving you an invalid URL, it just happens that browsers can figure out how to fix it.